# How to set current time of a Twitch video player programmatically?

Tags: javascript, twitch

I want to set the current time for a archived twitch video (e.g. https://www.twitch.tv/videos/319946452). I've tried to use video.currentTime or simulating clicking on coordinate but neither worked. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [fastSeek](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/fastSeek) method, available on HTMLMediaElements

```
const time = 60; // time in seconds.
const vidPlayer = document.querySelector('video');
vidPlayer.fastSeek(time);
```

for a widely supported method of seeking, you might use [currentTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime), which works both for setting and getting current time.

```
const time = 60; // time in seconds.
const vidPlayer = document.querySelector('video');
vidPlayer.currentTime = time;
```

Comment: Neither works for me. For fastSeek there is en error saying fastSeek is not a function. For currentTime the location of slider does go to that time, but the video gets stuck and won't play automatically.

Comment: that's strange, both are working for me.
try calling `vidPlayer.play();` after `vidPlayer.currentTime = time;`

Comment: Did you try it on the above url (https://www.twitch.tv/videos/319946452) in chrome developer tool console.

Comment: The second one works on chrome, after setting `currentTime` the video buffers for some time before playing again, you may also call `vidPlayer.play()` to make sure that the player will start after buffering.